# Minus the values of 2 specific rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, math, parameters

Im working on calculating through MySQL. The next values are day values and now I want to see what the difference is between the last row and 1 day (= 96 quarters) earlier. 
The line below is for the last and newest value:

```
SET @now = (SELECT * FROM solar.measurements WHERE `tag` LIKE '%18223.Inepro_Total_Forward_kWh[3]%' ORDER BY `measurements`.`timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1);
```

The next line is the value of 1 day ago. This is the same as 96 quarters.

```
SET @yesterday = (SELECT * FROM solar.measurements WHERE `tag` LIKE '%18223.Inepro_Total_Forward_kWh[3]%' ORDER BY `measurements`.`timestamp` DESC LIMIT 95,1);
```

Now I want to minus the newest value with the value 1 day ago so I know the difference between those values. The code below is what ive created right now:

```
CREATE EVENT Value_Test
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE
STARTS '2017-08-20 16:36:00'
DO
SET @now = (SELECT * FROM solar.measurements WHERE `tag` LIKE '%18223.Inepro_Total_Forward_kWh[3]%' ORDER BY `measurements`.`timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1);
SET @yesterday = (SELECT * FROM solar.measurements WHERE `tag` LIKE '%18223.Inepro_Total_Forward_kWh[3]%' ORDER BY `measurements`.`timestamp` DESC LIMIT 95,1);
SET @value = (@now - @yesterday);
INSERT INTO solar.measurements (nad, tag, value, timestamp) VALUES (18223, 'c18223.ValueDayTest', @waarde, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

When I want to execute this I get the following error: Error Code: 1048. Column 'value' cannot be null. Can someone help me by finding a solution? Thanks!

EDIT:
Answer to a question 
[Day Ago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIU5G.png)
[Today](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8XzX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SHOW CREATE EVENT Value_Test` would show you that your event wasn't done properly.

Try this:

```
Delimiter // 
CREATE EVENT Value_Test
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE
STARTS '2018-08-20 16:36:00'
DO
BEGIN
SET @now = (SELECT value FROM solar.measurements WHERE `tag` LIKE     
'%18223.Inepro_Total_Forward_kWh[3]%' ORDER BY `measurements`.`timestamp` DESC 
LIMIT 1);
SET @yesterday = (SELECT value FROM solar.measurements WHERE `tag` LIKE 
'%18223.Inepro_Total_Forward_kWh[3]%' ORDER BY `measurements`.`timestamp` DESC 
LIMIT 95,1);
SET @value = (@now - @yesterday);
INSERT INTO solar.measurements (nad, tag, value, timestamp) VALUES (18223, 
'c18223.ValueDayTest', @waarde, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
END
//

Delimiter ;
```

In case of the need to use compound statements inside an EVENT you need to put them under Begin/End